# Can't recreate this floating widget

Tags: flutter

I'm currently blocked trying to create a widget (like a tooltip box) that is represented by the image below. I should probably be able to create it by relying on a Painter class, but i'm not familiar doing so...

https://pasteboard.co/IgccNxD.png

(it's small, yes, max height = ~35px)

Comment: [Flutter Tooltip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html) doesn't resolve you problem?

Comment: The problem is the customization, with the CustomPaint i'm trying, but i'm unable to replicate the same design... With a `canvas.drawRRect` i can draw the rounded rectagle, but that pointy edge is not showing up and i don't know why...

Comment: You need to do this using drawPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code ended being something like:

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   Paint p = Paint()
     ..color = Colors.red
     ..isAntiAlias = true
     ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

   Offset nw = Offset(0, 0);
   Offset se = Offset(size.width, size.height * 0.8);

   final Rect rect = Rect.fromPoints(nw, se);
   final RRect r = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(10));

   canvas.drawRRect(r, p);

   Offset bottomPoint = Offset((size.width / 2), size.height);
   Offset rightPoint = Offset((size.width / 2) * 0.80, size.height * 0.80);
   Offset leftPoint = Offset((size.width / 2) * 1.20, size.height * 0.80);

   var path1 = Path()
     ..moveTo(rightPoint.dx, rightPoint.dy)
     ..lineTo(bottomPoint.dx, bottomPoint.dy)
     ..lineTo(leftPoint.dx, leftPoint.dy)
     ..lineTo(rightPoint.dx, rightPoint.dy);
   canvas.drawPath(path1, p);
}
```

For the text inside, I've stacked it above this painting.